# How to vertically center and right-align an image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want an image to be on the right side of a `<div>` but centered vertically.

[image]

I would like it to be flexbox or as simple as possible.

```css
#container1 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#div1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#some_image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="div1"><img id="some_image" src="some_image.gif"></div>
```

Comment: Partial/probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Comment: css alignment is one of the most answered subject on stackoverflow. You should show us what alternatives you have already tried, and why other answers here on the site doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You were close*

**Flexbox Solution**

```css
#div1 {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 1em auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;       /* vertical center */
      justify-content: flex-end; /* far right */
}

#some_image {
     width: 50px;
      height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img id="some_image" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-25-6.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way (compatible with all browsers) it's to use `transform: translate()` function combined with `position: absolute`. It allows to center (horizontally and/or vertically) without pre-known the size of the box, for example:

```css
#container1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* safari ios*/
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* old IE */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* standard */
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* safari ios*/
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* old IE */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* standard */
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
    <div id="div1">Something you want</div>
</div>

<div id="container1">
    <div id="div2">Something you want</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just want the image to the right and centered not anything else just the image

Comment: So that's it. See the first box. Is in the right and centered. Did you see?

Comment: Replace `Something you want` by your image.